# Filter rows matched string patterns (specific string + integer + another specific string) in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Given a DataFrame `df`:

```
   id                                        items
0   1  CRB Spot Index: Grease: First 2 Months: YoY
1   2                     CRB Spot Index: Textiles
2   3                    CRB Spot Index: Livestock
3   4      Korea: Export Value: First 10 Days: YoY
4   5      Korea: Export Value: First 20 Days: YoY
5   6      Korea: Import Value: First 20 Days: YoY
6   7      Korea: Import Value: First 10 Days: YoY
7   8    Vietnam: Import Value: First 2 Weeks: MoM
8   9    Vietnam: Import Value: First 3 Weeks: MoM
```

I want to filter items which match patterns: `First + integer + Days` or `First + integer + Weeks`, then create a new column to indicate them:

```
   id                                        items indicator
0   1  CRB Spot Index: Grease: First 2 Months: YoY       NaN
1   2                     CRB Spot Index: Textiles       NaN
2   3                    CRB Spot Index: Livestock       NaN
3   4      Korea: Export Value: First 10 Days: YoY         Y
4   5      Korea: Export Value: First 20 Days: YoY         Y
5   6      Korea: Import Value: First 20 Days: YoY         Y
6   7      Korea: Import Value: First 10 Days: YoY         Y
7   8    Vietnam: Import Value: First 2 Weeks: MoM         Y
8   9    Vietnam: Import Value: First 3 Weeks: MoM         Y
```

How could I do that using Pandas?

I use `df.loc[(df['items'].str.contains('First|Days', na=False)) & (df['items'].str.contains('First|Weeks', na=False)), 'indicators']='Y'`, it doesn't generate an expected result as shown above, also maybe there are other more concise answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check regex for match `First`, then `\s+` for space(s), then `\d+` for integers, `\s+` for again space(s) and last `Days|Weeks` for `Days` or `Weeks`:

```
df.loc[df['items'].str.contains('First\s+\d+\s+Days|Weeks', na=False), 'indicators']='Y'
print (df)
   id                                        items indicators
0   1  CRB Spot Index: Grease: First 2 Months: YoY        NaN
1   2                     CRB Spot Index: Textiles        NaN
2   3                    CRB Spot Index: Livestock        NaN
3   4      Korea: Export Value: First 10 Days: YoY          Y
4   5      Korea: Export Value: First 20 Days: YoY          Y
5   6      Korea: Import Value: First 20 Days: YoY          Y
6   7      Korea: Import Value: First 10 Days: YoY          Y
7   8    Vietnam: Import Value: First 2 Weeks: MoM          Y
8   9    Vietnam: Import Value: First 3 Weeks: MoM          Y
```

Comment: Thanks, is it necessary to add `regex=True` or it's optional for this case?

Comment: @ahbon - `regex=True` is default value in [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html), so should be removed.